# Federal ID number for West London University

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-w-2, tax-credit, ein

My son is attending West London University and I need to fill out tax form 1098T for the IRS to get the American Opportunity Credit.  They are asking for the university's "Federal ID number" (It may also be called "EIN" or "Tax ID"). I checked on the IRS website and the university is definitely in the eligibility list for American Opportunity Credit but I can't find the correct Federal ID number.  The IRS has a spreadsheet with a list of eligible universities and West London is on there with a code but it isn't a valid Federal ID number.  Where can I get this?  Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Call the university.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use funds received via the FAFSA the school has to be in the database.

[Federal School Code Search](https://fafsa.ed.gov/FAFSA/app/schoolSearch?locale=en_EN)

For state pick Foreign Country.

It looks like it is there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that was the kind of thing I was looking for.  Unfortunately H&R block and TurboTax online tax filers do not accept the code (039453).  They say the number should be in the format (NN-NNNNNNN) and that this code is invalid.  Please help

Comment: The code for FAFSA is different from the code for taxes.

Answer (score 1):

I have talked with the University, the U.S. Department of Education and the IRS.  My daughter attends University of Stirling in the U.K.  The school has never needed and does not feel they need a Federal EIN.  The U.S. Department of Education says to go to the IRS.  The IRS tax law department says go to the school.  I finally reached someone in IRS tax law today who was going to a supervisor to see if he could find anything further (I am looking for an exception as there is for the 1098T), but based on his attitude on the phone, I expect the answer will be to go back to the school because they will probably require the 1098T from the school next!  The school also does not provide that.  They give a certified letter.  The school is looking for a dictate from the U.S. that the EIN is required (instead of just from me).

Comment: I agree with the assertion that it would be odd for a foreign institution to be assigned a U.S. tax identifier, and with the institution that if they do indeed have one, it's certainly not their problem to know what it is since they're not in U.S. jurisdiction.

Answer (score 0):

**Get it from the school directly.** You aren't likely to find it by googling, just like you won't find your employer's federal ID by googling.

All schools I have attended provide a tax form called a 1098-T which has the federal ID for the school. Generally this is available by logging into the school's website with a student account, then looking for a section dealing with finances and/or taxes.

I don't know if this university furnishes that tax form to all students, since that's an American thing which wouldn't apply to most of their students. Still, you could have the student check to see if they can find the form or if they've been notified through their email about tax documents being available. If the student cannot locate the tax document, then **call the school**. Pretty much all American students will want to use claim that tax credit, so I'm sure they have someone available who can help you do so.

Comment: This sounds like a number that the U.S. government assigns to institutions. A university in the United Kingdom might happen to know theirs if they've been asked the question before; otherwise since it's a notion from outside their jurisdiction that doesn't have any involvement for them, I'm not sure I understand your reasoning.